# Disable copy paste function in a h:inputTextarea tag JSF(2.0)

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, java-ee-6

One of my clients do not want other sites to copy paste the content of a concrete textArea.
Currently i have an inputTextArea as readonly="true", but i still need to disable the copy & paste function. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make your JSF code to produce following HTML, note `oncopy` & `onpaste`

```
<textarea oncopy="return false;" onpaste="return false;">
```

Or enclose your components for which you want to disable copy & paste within following `div`

```
<div oncopy="return false;" onpaste="return false;">
    <!-------Your component should go here ----> 
</div>
```

Comment: I made a mistake i downvoted and navigated away i thought i clicked the tick mark. I realised lated  :)